# call functoin with async from http

Tags: angular

I am trying to enhance an existing angular app.
I have created a new component extending the exiting component, and injected my service which makes http get request with some parameters from the original component.

the http looks like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="entries$ | async as entries">
            <tr *ngFor="let entry of entries; index as i">
              <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
              <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
          </tr>
</ng-container>
```

In my component I create a function

```
  getIdInfo(id): Observable<any> {
    //calls my service but returns the observable of a get
    //bassicly this
    return this.http.post<any>(url, id);
  }
```

Then I try to use this from the http like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="entries$ | async as entries">
  <tr *ngFor="let entry of entries; index as i">
    <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="getInfo(entry.id) | async as info">
        {{ info }}
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

But info is not returned from the get. If however I subscribe in my service I can see the correct data.

I also tried to do this

```
 getInfo(id): Observable<any> {

    const os: Observable<String> = new Observable(o => {

      this.myService.getInfo(id).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        o.next(data);
      });

    });

    return os;

  }
```

Comment: I assume `getInfo (entry.id)` is a transcription error and is actually `getInfo(entry.id)`?

Comment: yes that is the case. I can see in the logs that indeed the function is called from the page.